# Regex match on specific pattern

Tags: regex

Definitely not an expert at Regex so I'm struggling here a bit. I'd like to create a pattern that will match the following format:

```
cat:hairy, rat:hairless               [correct]

cat:hairy, rat:hairless, dog:fat      [correct]

cat:hairy,      rat:hairless          [correct]



cat                                   [incorrect]

cat, dog                              [incorrect]

cat:hairy,                            [incorrect]

cat:hairy, monkey, dog:fat            [incorrect]

cat:hairy rat:hairless, dog:fat       [incorrect]
```

So far the regex I have is as follows:

```
((\S):(\S))
```

However, this does not work in all cases. Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**
*Language*: Java
*Format*: the xxx:yyy can be any letter or number, upper or lower case

Comment: What are the actual requirements for the `xxx:yyy` pairs? See https://regex101.com/r/ffWPnZ/1 - this is assuming these keys/values can contain any char but whitespace and `:`.

Comment: Can we assume that your words (`cat`, `fat`, `hairless` etc.) are always letter only (or is there any safe assumption we can take)? Also which language/tool do you want to implement this in?

Comment: Good question - sorry I should have clarified in the post. Any number or letter character, upper or lower case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ffWPnZ/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumerical chars
- `:`  - a colon
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumerical chars
- `(?:,\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+` - 1 or more sequences of

  - `,`  - comma
  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumerical chars
  - `:`  - a colon
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumerical chars
- `$` - end of string

Depending on the regex flavor and purpose, `[a-zA-Z0-9]` may be replaced with `[[:alnum:]]` (POSIX, Ruby, PCRE) or `\p{Alnum}` (Java). So, in Java, you'd use

```
.matches("\\p{Alnum}+:\\p{Alnum}+(?:,\\s+\\p{Alnum}+:\\p{Alnum}+)+")
```

Note there is no need for `^` and `$` as `.matches()` anchors the pattern by default.

Answer (score 0):

There is one scenario that is not listed as correct or incorrect, but implied correct by your first regex `((\S):(\S))`: a singleton `cat:hairy`. In this case, 
then Wiktor's excellent solution would be terminated with `*$` instead of `+$`.

Comment: I was not allowed to comment on the Wiktor's solution because I don't have the points. So I had to offer it up as an answer.